# Preview Bug with (Mountain) Lion -- hangs/crashes on repeat postscript openings

Tags: preview, crash, performance, postscript

I have been able to duplicate this error on both Lion and Mountain Lion.

- Open a(n) (enhanced) post-script file (either .ps or .eps) using preview.
- It should convert properly to PDF and be displayed
- Open the same file a second (or a few more) times
- Eventually preview will hang, then crash

For me, opening the same file 3 times is usually plenty.

Can other people reproduce this problem?

Any ideas for causes/fixes?

This seems like a big bug; im surprised it would have made it this far (especially from Lion).

After duplicating the problem, having Preview.app hang, and force quitting, my 'problem report' is at http://www.2shared.com/file/RjuzZbvC/Preview_2012-08-22-224825_Daed.html (too long to include, don't see another way to attach a file...)

Comment: I don't see a way to attach a file; so I uploaded it to 2shared -- link edited into the original post.

Comment: Sorry that I don't have a solution, but I'd like to point out that I am having the same problem with MY Mountain Lion. I don't know if it has to do with the laptop model, but I'm using a MacBook-Late 2008-Aluminum. Perhaps my computer is too old to handle some particular update that came from Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually submitted an bug-report to apple.  According to them there was already one open for the same thing.  They wouldn't give me any information about the issue, but it was solved with version 10.8.2